# Disable Magellan in Foundation 5

Tags: jquery, html, sass, zurb-foundation, magellan

Currently building a site Foundation 5 and its all great but Magellan isn't working the way I want it to and currently haven't got the time to work out why. Is there anyway I can disable it so I can just have the menu static at the top (rather than sticky on the browser) for the moment and come back to it later?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, simple really.

I literally just removed `="fixed"` in

```
<div class="nav" data-magellan-expedition="fixed">
```

Comment: Well that's why you should try things first before asking. Now mark this as the answer.

Comment: I did. Turns out I tried this after I posted. Apparently I can't mark this as the answer for another two days so you're stuck with it. Thanks for the helpful comment.